# Get All Pages from a given Category from wikipedia

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler, wikipedia-api

I am using [Wikipedia-api](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API) to extract all the text from pages of given category of wikipedia.

As given in the tutorial-

```
def print_categorymembers(categorymembers, level=0, max_level=2):
    for c in categorymembers.values():
        print("%s: %s (ns: %d)" % ("*" * (level + 1), c.title, c.ns))
        if c.ns == wikipediaapi.Namespace.CATEGORY and level <= max_level:
            print_categorymembers(c.categorymembers, level + 1)


cat = wiki_wiki.page("Category:Physics")
print("Category members: Category:Physics")
print_categorymembers(cat.categorymembers
```

but I am not being able to build the logic , how to do it ,this code just is giving me the all the pages and some pages which are nested into further another pages too.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract texts from page you have to use [text property](https://wikipedia-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wikipediaapi/api.html#wikipediaapi.WikipediaPage.text).

So your code could look like this:

```
cat = wiki_wiki.page("Category:Physics")
print("Category members: Category:Physics")
for p in cat.categorymembers.values():
  if p.namespace == wikipediaapi.Namespace.CATEGORY:
    # it is category, so you have to make decision
    # if you want to fetch also text from pages that belong
    # to this category
    print(p)
  elif p.namespace == wikipediaapi.Namespace.MAIN:
    # it is page => we can get text
    print(p)
    print(p.text)
```